# JavaScript sending base64 image string to servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

- my html code for selecting image and by clicking browserbutton,

  `<input id="image_file" type="file" class="frmitm" onChange="fileSelected();">`
- here for selcted code preview showing,

  `<img id="preview" width="50px" height="50px" border="1"  />`
- here javascript code for selected image & preview showing on page but when i alert or storing in the key its not getting full of string.

  `function selectedImage(){
  var oFile = document.getElementById('image_file').files[0];
  var oImage = document.getElementById('preview');
  var oReader = new FileReader();
  oReader.onload = function(e){
  oImage.src = e.target.result;
  var resultStr = oImage.src;
  var result = resultStr.split(",");
  $('#ImageKey').val(result[1]);
  };
  oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
  }`
- here **alert($('#ImageKey').val())** i got only half string only like,
- **/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD/7gAOQWRvYmUAZAAAAAAB/+ESC.....etc**,
- how to get full length of string value.or any other way to convert image to base64 string..
- if i saved server response base64 string in **var tempImgStr = response.ImgStr;**("/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD/7gAOQWRvYmUAZAAAAAAB/+ESC..etc")
- then **alert(tempImgStr)**, i will get half of string value only.
- any suggestions please..

Comment: Try `onloadend` instead of `onload`

Comment: thanks for replay..sorry not working.

Comment: when **alert(tempImgStr)** get only 1001 chars only.

Comment: 1001 maybe enougth, i had a 1000X1000 image in size of 30 bytes.